# Unable to inherit the class in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, overriding

I have Capture class as follow:-

```
namespace FrontEnd
{
    public partial class Capture : Window, DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
    {
        public Capture()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        protected virtual void init()
        {
            try
            {
                if (null != cap)
                    cap.EventHandler = this;
                else
                    SetPrompt("Cannot Use the Device right now");
            }
            catch { MessageBox.Show("Cannot Use the Device right now"); }
        }
   }
}
```

I have Enrollment class as follow:-

```
namespace FrontEnd
{
    public partial class Enrollment : Capture
    {

        protected override void init()
        {
            base.Init();
            Enroller = new DPFP.Processing.Enrollment();
            UpdateStatus();
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting three errors in Enrollment.cs:

> 1 - Partial declarations of 'Enrollment' must not specify different base classes.
>
> 2 - 'Enrollment.init()': No suitable method found to override.
>
> 3 - The name 'UpdateStatus' does not exist in current context.

I dont know where the problem exactly lies. Perhaps it is in the inheritance. Moreover, i am using WPF, so it might be possible that i am supposed to change xaml code as well in order to undergo inheritance.

Kindly help in resolving these errors.

Comment: you have another partial class `Enrollment ` somewhere else causing this error.

Comment: Did you intend to make these classes `partial` ? Which means that there might be another file that contains a another part of the class and maybe has a different inheritance definition.

Comment: also dont forget to use `using` statement to include all the required files. check if they are named correctly and are in correct place.

Comment: Ok. I have tried changing the names of both classes, in case if there are multiple classes of same name. But i am still facing these three errors. And all the necessary libraries are included in the projected.
@M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: well, I did not intend to make these classes 'partial'.
@user3185569

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that like JAVA, multiple inheritance is also not allowed in C# as well. And for the class Capture you are inheriting from two classes.

```
public partial class Capture : Window, DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
```

There can be a work around for that. You can use multilevel inheritance. That will resolve the issue.

Comment: this was what caught my attention too, but it doesn't quite say if it is inheritance of classes or implementation of interfaces going on.. since the second one is an eventhandler my guess is that one is an interface, so the question is missing vital information on what is inherited/implemented

Answer (score 1):

1 - Partial declarations of 'Enrollment' must not specify different base classes.

My first guess on this case would be, that you have another class that is also partial and derives from a different class than Capture.

2 - 'Enrollment.init()': No suitable method found to override.

The problem here is, that the base classes Capture, Window and Eventhandler do not define the init() method so you cannot override it. If you remove the override from the init method you should be good to go.

Probably the issue is a simple typo. In this method you call a Init() method and the override is a **lower case init**

3 - The name 'UpdateStatus' does not exist in current context.

Same issue like in 2. There is no UpdateStatus in the base class.

I also think, that it is an issue to derive from multiple classes becaus like java , c# does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere else in your code you have another class called FrontEnd.Enrollment. This will derive from something other than Capture. This is causing error 1.

Because the compiler cannot tell what the correct base class is you will not be able to resolve any members of that class. This is causing errors 2 & 3

So correct the issue with the multiple base classes and you'll be fine.